# dynamic rails helpers (eg. link_to method, method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dynamic, helper

I was wondering how to get some dynamic abilities for my rails helpers:

```
<h3><%= link_to object.name, ("#{object.class_path.to_s}")_path(object) %></h3>
```

In this case, throwing it the object's class into a link to. I'm getting confused on how to throw a method within a helper method.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you have already solved it, but for future reference with your original approach you would have had to use send like this: `link_to object.name, send("#{object.class_path.to_s}_path", object)`

Comment: Ah, it's 'send', got it. Was wondering how that worked. 
Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to link to the instance of the object?

```
<%= link_to object.name, object %>
```

Rails can construct a `#show` link from that.

You can use `polymorphic_path` for more complicated/nested situations:

```
<%= link_to object.name, polymorphic_path([:edit, @user, object]) %>
```

...as a synonym for `edit_user_#{object.class}_path(@user,object)`

Comment: I like that polymorphic_path. Cheers for the tip!

Comment: polymorphic_path is the better option, I was searching to internet about this topic.

I think @eric only forget give us the link to [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved this by doing this instead:

```
<%= link_to object.name, url_for(object) %>
```

Are there any performance or usability issues using `url_for` instead of something_path? Is there any difference at all?