# Helper function for dynamic routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone please help me create a helper function in order to dynamically get the controller action path and name.

```
<% if action_name.eql? "show" %>
  <li><%= link_to '<i class="icon-fixed-width icon-pencil"></i> Edit'.html_safe, edit_contact_path(@contact) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to '<i class="icon-fixed-width icon-trash"></i> Delete'.html_safe, @contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>
<% end %>
```

Essentially, I would like to create a helper for this piece of the code:

```
edit_contact_path(@contact)
```

I want to be able to insert any controller name for "contact", so that I can dynamically use the larger piece of code above throughout my site.

Thanks!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539168/dynamic-rails-helpers-eg-link-to-method-method

Comment: Is object defined in a helper somewhere, or is that a built-in Rails helper?

Comment: `object` is just a variable, in your case it would be `@contact`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `[:edit, @contact]` instead of the explicit method name.

```
<li><%= link_to '.... Edit', [:edit, @contact] %></li>
```

Substitute `@contact` with whichever variable you wish. I find the array syntax much more readable, and prefer it everywhere. Compare:

```
 = link_to "Edit", edit_user_post_comment_path(@user, @post, @comment)
```

vs

```
 = link_to "Edit", [:edit, @user, @post, @comment]
```

Comment: Can I use this for "New" also?

Comment: Yes, though, there's not much need. For a new record, the path is simply `[@record]` and a POST request.